# Layer Normalization with Python Keras

Tags: python, keras

I'm studying the paper "An Introduction to Deep Learning for the Physical Layer".
 While implementing the proposed network with `python keras`, I should normalize output of some layer.

One way is simple L2 Normalization (`||X||^2 = 1`), where X is a tensor of former layer output. I can implement simple L2 Normalization by the following code:

```
from keras import backend as K
Lambda(lambda x: K.l2_normalize(x,axis=1))
```

The other way, what I want to know, is `||X||^2 ≤ 1`.
Is there any way that constrains the value of layer outputs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can apply constraint on layer wights (kernels) for some keras layers. For example on a `Dense()` layer like:

```
from keras.constraints import max_norm
from keras.layers import Dense
model.add(Dense(units, kernel_constraint=max_norm(1.)))
```

But keras layer does not accept an `activity_constraint` argument, However they accept `activity_regularizer` and you can use that to implement the first kind of regularization easier).

You can also clip output values of any layer to have maximum norm `1.0` (although I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for). For example if you're using a `tensorflow` backend, you can define a custom activation layer that clips the value of the layer by norm like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def norm_clip(x):
    return tf.clip_by_norm(x, 1, axes=[1])
```

And use it in your model like:

```
model.add(Dense(units, activation=norm_clip))
```